# What does "look up to it" means?

Tags: idioms

Will you please tell me what "didn't look up to it" in the senteces below means?

''The press were writing up right through that season that I should have been in the side, then in the first innings I made 22 in two hours and they said I **didn't look up to it** so they changed their mind,'' Moss said.

''One minute they're saying you should be in the side, the next he **didn't look up to it**. I thought I did all right in the second innings.''

Read more: http://www.smh.com.au/sport/cricket/george-bailey-hopes-to-echo-debut-of-onetest-wonder-moss-20131118-2xrar.html#ixzz38lZfstni

Answer (score 6):

> [***look*** sense 12](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/look?s=t) *- seem, appear to be, give the impression of being*
>    [***to be up to [it, doing something]***](http://www.englishlesson.co.uk/learnenglish/c_advanced/up_to_etc.htm) *- to be **able** to do something* (often, *fit/healthy/strong* enough)

The highlighted passage can thus be read as...

> *...they said I didn't **seem to be sufficiently skilled (or fit) to play**, so they dropped me from the side*

---

The second citation just looks confusing because there are three different pronouns all refering to the same person (***you*** when "they" are addressing the speaker, ***he*** when one of "them" is speaking to someone else, and ***I*** when the speaker refers to himself).

Answer (score -1):

Looking up to someone means you want to follow there footsteps or you really admire who they are and think there really amazing for what they do, so you look up to them like looking up at a hero or your role model.

Comment: Um, you do realize that the phrase is "look up to something", not "look up to someone"?

Comment: What @MARamezani said. It's true that *in other contexts* this meaning might apply. But it's completely irrelevant to this particular question.